# LDAP for 8 machines and 4 users

Tags: ssh, authentication, ldap, ssh-keys

I'm currently administering about 8 server machines running Ubuntu. Right now, the 4 people with authority to ssh to the systems all share the same private key. This was fine when it was two people and two machines but it's not a good solution anymore.  Should I setup an LDAP server?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [SME Server](http://wiki.contribs.org/Main_Page)? Easy to set up and get going within 30mins or less (including LDAP setup). A short list of what SME Server offers can be found [here](http://wiki.contribs.org/SME_Server:About). You could also look at [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) or [389 Directory Server](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/) for authentication.